# Qt QOrganizerItemSortOrder not working when fetching calendar events from EDS

Tags: c++, qt

I'm fetching calendar events from EDS (Evolution Data Server). I'm trying to sort them:

- all day events come first
- other scheduled events, by time ascending

However, sort doesn't work properly.

I'm doing a call to (QOrganizerItemFetchRequest)

```
request.start()
```

which asynchronously fetches events. When they're available, I fetch available events using parameterless

```
QOrganizerManager::items() // in onResultReceived()
```

Recurring events (at certain times of day) always seem to come first, before single scheduled events, like so:

- 8:00 event A (recurring)
- 12:00 event B (recurring)
- 10:00 event C
- 11:00 event D

I'm turning to StackOverflow, as I've exhausted Qt documentation and did my best to search for possible solutions with Google.

```
QOrganizerItemSortOrder sortAllDay;
sortAllDay.setDirection(Qt::SortOrder::AscendingOrder);
sortAllDay.setDetail(QOrganizerItemDetail::TypeEventTime,
                     QOrganizerEventTime::FieldAllDay);
QOrganizerItemSortOrder sortStartTime;
sortStartTime.setDirection(Qt::SortOrder::AscendingOrder);
sortStartTime.setDetail(QOrganizerItemDetail::TypeEventTime,
                        QOrganizerEventTime::FieldStartDateTime);
QList<QOrganizerItemSortOrder> sorting;
sorting << sortAllDay << sortStartTime;

request.setManager(&manager);
request.setSorting(sorting);
request.setStartDate(startDate);
request.setEndDate(endDate);

QObject::connect(&request, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QOrganizerAbstractRequest::State)),
                 this, SLOT(onStateChanged(QOrganizerAbstractRequest::State)));
QObject::connect(&request, SIGNAL(resultsAvailable()),
                 this, SLOT(onResultReceived()));
```